# Como Atualizar a versão do PHP no WampServer?

Tags: php, versionamento, wamp

Alguém sabe como atualizar a versão do PHP para a mais recente no WampServer?

Comment: Veja: http://www.websanova.com/blog/php/manually-adding-php-versions-to-wamp#.UyC-q_mK_8M e também http://www.dotkernel.com/php-development/how-to-upgrade-wamp-to-php-5-3-4/. Testei e funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

**Eu acho que você quer isso:**

1º: Faz o download da última versão do php aqui [http://www.baixaki.com.br/download/php.htm[1](http://www.baixaki.com.br/download/php.htm)

2º: Supondo que você usa sistema operacional Windows e fez a instalação padrão vai em **C:\wamp\bin\php** e deleta a pasta da versão antiga do php e cola a nova aí.

3º: Tenha atenção para problemas de incompatibilidade e nomes diferenciados de diretórios, em último caso renomeia a pasta da nova versão do php para o nome que tinha na pasta antiga XD.

4º: Por último se quiser crie um script com o código abaixo, salva e executa. Deverá mostrar a versão do php que você baixou e algumas informações a mais.

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: Não recomende baixar por site de terceiros, tem muitos anúncios e vírus. Use os sites oficiais em vez disto.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode encontrar vários PHP addons para baixar [aqui](http://www.wampserver.com/en/php-addons/), então é só instalar a nova versão do PHP e pronto.

Agora, se preferir fazer todo o processo manualmente, acredito que essa [discussão](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,113423,113435#msg-113435) (em inglês) do próprio fórum do WampServer poderá ajudar.

Comment: sim, eu já acessei mas não entendi muito bem como fazer a atualização, tipo no site do php tem a ultima versão para download mas não sei como implementar no wamp

Comment: Se for usar um desses addons PHP basta instalá-los e depois clicar no WampServer -> PHP -> Version -> e selecionar a versão desejada. Obs: não esqueça de verificar se a versão do PHP é compatível com a do Apache.